# pgfkeys error in ytableau package

Tags: pgfkeys, ytableau

I'm running TeX Live 2013 Debian (on a Linux Mint 17 machine). I'm getting the following error when I try to load the `ytableau` package:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pgfkeys.sty' not found.
```

When I search the package manager for any packages that mention `pgfkeys` I find the only match is in `texlive-pictures` which is already installed on my system, the docs say that `texlive-pictures` includes

> pgfkeyx -- Extended and more robust version of pgfkeys.
>   pgfopts -- LaTeX package options with pgfkeys.

Is it that someone renamed `pgfkeys` to `pgfkeyx` and thus broke backwards compatibility with other packages? That would indeed be unfortunate.

Any help much appreciated. Here is my entire input file that produced the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Title}
\author{Some author} 
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd try to either: 1) Find the `pgfkeys.sty` on the web and put it in my compilation folder; or 2) Make a local copy of `ytableau.sty` and change the requiments from `pgfkeys` to `pgfkeyx`. At least as a temporary solution.

Comment: BTW, In my installation of `Texlive` there is a `pgfkeys.sty` under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.tex`

Comment: `pgfkeys` is used by TikZ the most. So nothing will change its name. It's almost certain that your installation is problematic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a no-repro case and works without any problems with an up-to-date system.